# Go Web App: How to route PHP scripts to PHP-FPM from Golang

Tags: go

I have one main web site and numerous small web sites. I'm currently using Nginx & PHP for all of this. My plan is to do away with both and build a single web app in Go that will serve everything, which will hopefully reduce load and memory (especially since some of the pages are very computationally heavy.)

My issue is that it would be a serious waste of time for me to try to port things like rarely used PHPBB forums to Go. So I'd like to have the main web site all served from the Go web app, but some of the other sites can remain as PHP.

My question is: can I use the Go web app to route requests for PHP scripts to PHP-FPM?

I would like it so that I can do away with Nginx, the web app will handle all of the incoming traffic and serve the main site directly from its own code, but for less important sites that are still in PHP these can be served by the Go app routing these requests to PHP-FPM (along with all the full request info including cookies, POST vars, etc.)

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess would be that nginx is the least of your problems and I would have recommended you to use nginx in combination with Go. This would solve your PHP/Go routing problem as well. Do you have any reason for getting rid of nginx?

Comment: Not really, it just seems redundant to have it on there running and wasting my CPU. Especially since all it will be doing is routing to PHP-FPM anyway.

Comment: Do you have a common session storage for all these sites ? An external session storage like redis/memcached will be useful for migration.

Comment: The sites have separate sessions. I was going to implement my own sessions for all sites that will be converted to Go. The PHP ones can use their own PHP sessions.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an ancient post, but here's my answer since I've had to research this for myself after running into essentially the same issue.

**TL;DR I suggest proxying to Nginx via HTTP and letting it talk to PHP-FPM - not because Nginx is better or faster or shinier or whatever, but because this code path is orders of magnitude more well tested and maintained and the disadvantages are minimal.**

Two obvious approaches:

A) Use Nginx and proxy request through go to PHP.  This can be done with httputil as described in @fabrizioM's answer, and is essentially proxying the request via HTTP to Nginx which then converts it to FastCGI and calls PHP-FPM.

B) Use an implementation of the FastCGI protocol to call to PHP-FPM directly from Go.  I haven't tried this, but there are a number of Go libraries out there which purport to do this, including:

- https://github.com/tomasen/fcgi_client
- https://github.com/yookoala/gofast
- https://gist.github.com/wofeiwo/3727055
- And more...

n.b. I realize some of these probably didn't exist with the question was asked.

The first one above has 21 stars as of this writing.

IMO, while Nginx is a great webserver, there is little to gain from it over serving static files in Go.  However, there is one big thing you gain by using Nginx here and it is the stability and maintenance of that FastCGI code.  Clearly calling via FastCGI in Go is not an extremely popular approach, and I don't know how much I trust the implementation. On the other hand, there are bazillions of PHP devs out there who swear by Nginx+PHP-FPM and it is well tested and maintained.

There are some other nice perks when using HTTP for proxying, e.g. it's more likely to work correctly when you, during local development, forward requests from your Go process over the Internet to wherever your PHP server is.  This makes it easy to hack away on your Go app without having to run a local copy of all of the PHP stuff and yet still be able to see everything functional.

So while both approaches are viable, my suggestion is to include Nginx solely because it is a much better supported code path that your requests flow through, has some practical local dev advantages and the performance loss is negligible.  I think those are much stronger arguments than the "Nginx is great at serving static files" or "has low memory usage", etc. arguments.

Answer (score 2):

PHP-FPM is listening on an unix socket. So you can simply connect to its unix socket using the [`net.Dial`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial) method:

```
conn, err:= net.Dial("unix","", "/path/to/php-fpm.sock")
```

then write what you need on the resulting connection. You may use the [`net.Pipe`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Pipe) method, which will require use the `net` package for connection handling (or hijacking those of a more classic `http` server).

That said, I would however advice against handling this with go: nginx is highly efficient, fast, has a low memory usage, and will do this job far better than you. What you should do (IMHO) is to port each application you want to go, then use nginx as a reverse proxy. If you're after performance, you can use unix socket for communication between nginx and apps, as it will be faster than listening on a TCP port.

Comment: My idea was that only one instance of the app would be running if the website were compiled into the web app. This means that session variables could be kept in memory instead of being reloaded, as well as static files being kept in memory. It would mean virtually no IO for the entire site. All of this performance advantage would be lost if I were to use Nginx and this repeated executed the site every time a page or file were accessed. Doesn't that make using Nginx very inefficient? Also I'm not sure what Nginx does that makes it better than my Go web app - are there security risks?

Comment: Even behind nginx and split into small chunks, your apps will still be running and keeping vars in memory. And unless you apps are really one app, you don't have any reason to share session variables, static files, etc. You won't gain anything on I/O, and nginx very efficient at serving static files.

Comment: And maintaining multiple small apps is easier than one big. Espacially if those apps are unrelated.

Comment: I still fail to see any advantage in using Nginx. Nginx does not cache static files in memory. If a user visits 10 pages, each with 20 static files, and there are 10,000 visitors per day then that is 2 million IO requests per day that can be converted into zero. I do not understand at all what the supposed advantage of Nginx is other than it is easier to use, which is quite clearly not my motivation, else I would not be using Go at all. There is no point using Go unless one is after efficiency.

Comment: My point is that between OS caching, nginx caching and all, constantly served files may not be cached in memory but I don't think you will notice a real overhead. Nginx is known to server static content to a virtually unlimited number of clients with a constant memory footprint and an almost-constant processing time.

Comment: Nginx is easier to use, and (I maintain it) probably better at what it do than what you would code by hand. My point is that Nginx (and other servers as well) is an excellent tool that fullfill most of your app-unrelated requirements (static file serving, multi-app routing, logging, etc) and that you don't have to re-invent the wheel to be efficient.

Comment: If you really are after performance, why not porting your apps to C ? That's more efficient that Go, and far more difficult to use. It seem that the first is your goal, and you don't care about the second…

Comment: Why not write it in assembly? Somewhere there is a line, but the line is most certainly not as high as putting millions of file reads on my server every day when all of this could be avoided by integrating it into the web app, neither is it as low as spending several years writing the code in Assembly for every ounce of efficiency. I have yet to hear a good reason why Nginx should be used, other than it will be easier to implement. It does not appear to be too difficult to do it in Go in order to outweigh its advantages.

Comment: I really think that you're missing the point of using nginx, and over-evaluating the static file serving overhead. I will only add that the flexibility of multiple apps behind a reverse proxy outweight in my opinion the little performance you could (and I'm not convainced that you would) gain by integrating everything into one big app that handle everything.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to another url you can use `httputil.HostReverseProxy`

```
    origin := "http://php.website.com"
    originUrl, err := url.Parse(origin)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(originUrl)
    prev := proxy.Director

    proxy.Director = func(req *http.Request) {
        prev(req)
        req.Host = originUrl.Host
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/php", proxy.ServeHTTP)
```

Comment: php-fpm is not a http server.